# How to get plot of Ripley's K function (Kest) for temporal data in R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, spatial, spatio-temporal

I have the temporal data of Landslide events in CSV format. My data consists of Year, Month, and Day of events. I want to see if there is temporal clustering for events or not by using Ripley's K function (kest function in R studio). Actually, I got the Ripley'K function plot for spatial data (Latitude and longitude) by using the Spatstat library with envelope using Monte Carlo Simulations, but I am unable to do it with the temporal dataset with envelope using Monte Carlo Simulations, if I got the plot but envelop function is not working for my temporal dataset.
**What do I want to do?**
I want to make a Ripley plot with an envelope to analyze the temporal clustering for the events by using R studio.
**Where am I stuck?**
I am not able to get the plot as well as the high and low confidence band that's why ultimately I am unable to get an envelope.

Comment: R Studio is an IDE so the question had nothing to do with R Studio.  That’s why I edited the title.